# get_feature_names for each label

Tags: machine-learning, tfidfvectorizer

I'm new to machine learning, started with multilable Text classification. I'm able to classify the new data based on trained modle. however some lables are miss predicted.

f
I want to see the weightage of the tokens or may be called features used for L1 and L2.

or example there are two lables L1 and L2. new records are associated to L1 but they are predicted as L2, these 2 have similar tokens with few difference.

My question to all is , can I see the features mapped by tfidfvectorizer to L1 and L2.something like below using get_feature_names() and 'Y' variables.

L1(hockey)-- 'ball','ground','net','stick'
L2(cricket)-- 'ball','ground','stick','stumps'

Comment: tfidf does not do what you are asking here.TFIDF just converts raw data into matrix of features

Comment: do we have any alternative where i can get the desired output

Comment: Explain your dataset and the machine learning model you are using for text classification.

Comment: The data set has 2 columns, one the category and the 2nd is the english text that explains the  column. this is actually the problem incident management data.

we are trying to map the new incident into respective buckets. the text contains job names and the error codes associated to the failures. We have 30 odd categories manually identified, out of theses 6 have mostly similar text with a few unique words, this is making the confusion.

We tried SVM,RF,NB and KNN, and we got the better results with SVM. SO our model is finalized to SVM.